# How we can make a div placed inside a link tag to be non-navigated

Tags: html, reactjs, react-router-dom

I am having a tile. Clicking anywhere on it should redirect to a new page.I have kept my complete code inside Link tag so that whenever i will click on any part of that div, it will navigate to the new page. But inside that Link tag, there is a subdiv, clicking on which i don't want to perform redirection.
The problem i am facing is that if i will close the link tag before that particular div on which i don't want to perform redirection then, remaining area of the parent div is also becoming non-clickable except the written p tags. How i can make only that particular div non-redirectable.

```
       <Link to={{ pathname: '/demo_summary/'>
            <div className="ctd-tile" style={{ margin: "10px", height"260px" }}>
              <p>VERSION: {i.version}</p><br />
              <p>Complexity: {i.complexity}</p><br />

              <div className="col-md-4">}}>
                  <img src={require("../images/icon1.png")} title="DEMO PLAN" /></Link>
              </div>

              <div className="col-md-4">
                <input type="image"  title="View HTML" src={require("../images/viewAsHtml.png")} style={{width: "40%", cursor: "pointer"}} onClick={(e) => { e, that.openReport(e, i.demoName) }}/>
              </div>

              <div className="col-md-4">
                <Download file={i.name} content={text}>
                  <img src={require("../images/download.png")} title="DOWNLOAD" style={{ width: "25%", cursor: "pointer" }} />
                </Download>
              </div>
            </div>
          </Link>
```

I want to make second div having title as "View HTML" to be non-redirectable.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`event.stopPropagation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) on the `onClick` of the `div` you want to stop redirecting.

When you have nested tags, if you click on one tag, you will trigger the `onClick` of the tag and the parent `onClick` too.

```js
function App() {

  return (
    <div onClick={() => console.log('parent onClick')} >
      <button onClick={() => console.log('button click')}>Click me</button>
    </div>
  )
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("app");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

But if you use `event.stopPropagation` on the children div. The parent tag wont have it `onClick` event triggered.

```js
function App() {

  return (
    <div onClick={() => console.log('parent onClick')} >
      <button onClick={e => {
        e.stopPropagation()
        console.log('button onClick')
        }}>Click me</button>
    </div>
  )
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("app");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

So now you know that, just add `e.stopPropagation()` to the `onClick` of the div you don't want to trigger the `Link`'s `onClick`.

## Edit:

Your code have something very weird

```
onClick={(e) => { e, that.openReport(e, i.demoName) }} // ????
```

But what you should do is

```
onClick={(e) => { 
    e.stopPropagation();
    that.openReport(e, i.demoName);
}}
```

Here is the full code

```
<div className="col-md-4"             
    onClick={(e) => { 
          // added stopPropagation in the correct place
          e.stopPropagation();
          that.openReport(e, i.demoName);
     }}
>
    <input 
        type="image"  
        title="View HTML" 
        src={require("../images/viewAsHtml.png")} 
        style={{width: "40%", cursor: "pointer"}} 
        onClick={(e) => { 
          // added stopPropagation in the correct place
          e.stopPropagation();
          that.openReport(e, i.demoName);
        }}
    />
</div>
```

Comment: e.stopPropagation() is no helping

Comment: @AnjaliChaudhary check the code snippet. The parent would be the `Link` and the button would be the div that don't redirect. If it doesn't work, please explaing what you are doing, maybe you are adding it in the wrong place

Comment: <div className="col-md-4" onClick={e => {e.stopPropagation() }}>
                    <input type="image"  title="View as HTML" src={require("../images/viewAsHtml.png")} style={{width: "40%", cursor: "pointer"}} onClick={(e) => { e, that.openReport(e, item.modelName) }}/>
                  </div>

Comment: on div i am having single onClick only. second on click is for the image i have added to that div, on its own click i am calling a different function that is responsible for performing api calls and other functionalities.

Comment: add `stopPropagation` to the image too?

Comment: It is still getting redirecting

Comment: Yes, i want to add stopPropagation to the image too

Comment: Can you provide you code in codesanbox or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

Pass the `history` to your component as prop then use push to redirect or stop the event with

```
e.stopPropagation();
```

**Example:**

```
const navigation = ({ history }) => {
      return (
        <div>
          <a
            onClick={() => {
              history.push("/cool");
            }}
          >
            rediction
            <span
              onClick={e => {
                e.stopPropagation();
              }}
            >
              none redirection
            </span>
          </a>
        </div>
      );
    };
```